# Negation in Roblox Lua

Tags: lua, roblox

I have a problem with negation in roblox lua. I can't find anywhere how to do that. I've tried to use this code:
`script.Parent.DoorRoot.CanCollide != script.Parent.DoorRoot.CanCollide`

It didn't worked so I tried with

`script.Parent.DoorRoot.CanCollide = !script.Parent.DoorRoot.CanCollide`

But it still didn't worked. Can somebody help me with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking for equality use `~=`

```
local foo = 1 ~= 0
```

If you're trying to negate a value, use the `not` keyword

```
script.Parent.DoorRoot.CanCollide = not script.Parent.DoorRoot.CanCollide
```